# Why would Xamarin Forms Activity Indicator not be rendered on iOS?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms 2.3.2.127 for development of a mobile application.

I have an activity indicator that sits within a StackLayout, which is in turn contained within a Grid Row.

The activity indicator renders on Android, however does not render on iOS.

The controls XAML is as follows:

```
<ActivityIndicator WidthRequest="50" Color="Red" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="True"/>
```

There are no bindings applied at present, and there have been no changes to the underlying control using CustomRenderers.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue, or if there are any common bugs? This has occured before in other projects and rectified itself without any changes randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem & not visible during operation, I m using MVVM Binding, I solved it by invoking the MainThread

XAML

```
<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding PBVisibility}" IsRunning="{Binding PBRunning}" Color="Black" />
```

ViewModel

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    PBVisibility = true;
                    PBRunning = true;
                    RaisePropertyChanged ("PBVisibility");
                    RaisePropertyChanged ("PBRunning");

                });
```

You run that in MainThread & it will work.

Comment: There is no invocation, the element has no bindings as yet, with static values the indicator should simply appear and always be running, however it is not rendering at all .

Comment: I put Simply too but not showing in iOS, After that i use Binding & runInMainThread & then It Appears & run

Comment: please re-read my question, my issue is not with the activity indicator appearing on a change, it is with it being rendered at all, the controls code is being run, it is just not being rendered, as it is working fine on android it is not an issue with bindings or being invoked on correct thread